# How to replace double quotes in Microsoft WORD using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

Following successfully replaces `Apple` with `Mango` in a `WORD` document if it has the word `Apple`:

```
myDocRange.Find.Execute(FindText: "Apple", Format: false, ReplaceWith: "Mango", MatchWildcards: true, Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

But if the document has a double quote `"` and you want to replace it with `TEST`, following does nothing:

```
myDocRange.Find.Execute(FindText: "\"", Format: false, ReplaceWith: "TEST", MatchWildcards: true, Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

**Remark**: Instead of using `"\""`, if I use `""""` or `@"""` I get a syntax error.

However, following works in `VBA`. But I need it to work in `C#`:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = """"
    .Replacement.Text = "TEST"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use character codes to find special characters, according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute):

**FindText:**

> You can search for special characters by specifying
>   appropriate character codes. For example, "^p" corresponds to a
>   paragraph mark and "^t" corresponds to a tab character.

So you need to use `^34` for `"`:

```
myDocRange.Find.Execute(FindText: "^34", Format: false, ReplaceWith: "TEST", MatchWildcards: true, Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```